# Get response from loading movie to youtube

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api, zend-gdata

i am using the ZEND Gdata and youtube api to upload vidoes to youtube
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Direct_Upload

When I upload a Video how do I capture the Video ID that was generated and also the youtube link ?

```
try 
{
   $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry,$uploadUrl,'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
} 
catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) 
{
   echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
} 
catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) 
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry,$uploadUrl,'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
```

returns a  `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry` object.

[The Zend Framework API docs for `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry.html#%5CZend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry) lists all the methods and properties that class makes available. [There is similar documentation for all Zend Framework classes](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/), and it's automatically generated, so it's often a good place to go if the manual doesn't answer a question.

From looking there, I'd say that you'd call:

- `$newEntry->getVideoId()` to get the video ID
- `$newEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl()` to get the video URL